# How to loop through 0-9 in a sql query?

Tags: amazon-redshift

This is redshift. I have an update command that looks like this:

```
UPDATE users
SET birthday = temp_users.birth_date
FROM public.users as gpu 
INNER JOIN temp_schema.users_birth_dates_with_row_numbers AS temp_users ON gpu.id = temp_users.id
WHERE mod(temp_users.row_id, 10) = 0 -- this is what I want to change from 0 -> 9
;
```

For context: I want to run this time times with a different modulo number. How can I do this? Row id is basically created with the `row_number` function and I want to do this in batches so that it doesn't hold any locks for too long.

Answer (score 2):

SQL WHILE loop syntax and example
The syntax of the WHILE loop in SQL looks like as follows:

`WHILE condition BEGIN {...statements...} END`

Example:

```
DECLARE @Counter INT 

SET @Counter=0
WHILE ( @Counter <= 9)
  BEGIN
  PRINT 'The counter value is = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@Counter)
  SET @Counter  = @Counter  + 1
END
```

Comment: sorry my mistake. can this be done in redshift?

Comment: yes you can do it  redshift support different conditional statement
For example 
https://dwgeek.com/redshift-conditional-statements-if-loop-while-for-continue-and-exit.html/

check this site